# Laravel-Cannot save record with belongsTo relationship

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5.3, belongs-to

I have two tables

- Category
- Media

**Fields for Category**

- id
- name
- description
- thumbnail
- banner

**Fields for Media**

- id
- title
- source

What I am trying to do is, whenever I create new category, after uploading thumbnail and banner, a new record will be created for both of them in media table and ids of those records will be stored against particular category.

Each media will belong to one category only and one category will have two medias only.

Thumbnail and banner from category will store the media ids from media.

**This is my code**

```
$category = Category::create($input);
$media = Media::create([
          'title'  => $photoName,
          'source' => $photoName,
        ]);
```

$category->media->attach($media->id);

**Category Model**

```
public function media()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Media');
    }
```

**Media Model**

```
 public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
```

Can anyone please help me with what I am doing wrong here

Appreciated,

Comment: How are these two tables linked? One of both should have a foreign key to the other table.

Comment: Can a gategory have more than one media ? because i think in normal case a category has many medias !!

Comment: I hope you need to checkyour table becuase there is no relatioship with both table.

Comment: Can you state the problem here?  do you get any error or something that we can debug?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you need to check your table becuase there is no relatioship with both table. if you will do this then your code will work

You should use these table schema in laravel 5.4

```
        Schema::create('Category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique();
        $table->string('description')->nullable();
        $table->string('thumbnail')->nullable();
        $table->string('banner')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    // Create table for associating roles to users (Many-to-Many)
    Schema::create('Media', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->string('source')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('Category')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->primary(['id', 'category_id']);
    });
```

Comment: Actually I did not mentioned that thumbnail and banner from category table will contain media id from media table

Answer (score 0):

you should add foreign key to your Category fields:

```
 id,media_id,name,description,thumbnail,banner
```

now you can use relatioship :

```
$category = Category::findOrFail(1);    // get category with id = 1 
$media = Media::create([
          'title'  => $photoName,
          'source' => $photoName,
        ]);
$category->media()->associate($media);
```

for more information :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one